# What does highlighted colors in Sublime Text 2 signify?

Tags: css, colors, background, sublimetext2, highlight

I have this code in a file:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
```

Sublime Text 2 seems to highlight the background of `indigo` and `violet` with a light blue color:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I've tried out some more colors and most of them like `chocolate`, `aliceblue`, `pink` etc get highlighted but some others like `maroon`, `teal`, `silver` etc doesn't.

What does the blue highlight mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are ["Extended color keywords"](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#svg-color)

> X11 colors [[X11COLORS](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#ref-X11COLORS)] supported by popular browsers with the addition
>   of gray/grey variants from SVG 1.0. The resulting list is precisely
>   the same as the [SVG 1.0 color keyword names](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords). This specification
>   extends their definition beyond SVG.

The relevant part of CSS.tmLanguage:

```xml
...
<dict>
<key>color-values</key>
<dict>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        ...
        <dict>
            <key>comment</key>
            <string>These colours are mostly recognised but will not validate. ref: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colornames.asp</string>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>\b(aliceblue|antiquewhite|aquamarine|azure|beige|bisque|blanchedalmond|blueviolet|brown|burlywood|cadetblue|chartreuse|chocolate|coral|cornflowerblue|cornsilk|crimson|cyan|darkblue|darkcyan|darkgoldenrod|darkgray|darkgreen|darkgrey|darkkhaki|darkmagenta|darkolivegreen|darkorange|darkorchid|darkred|darksalmon|darkseagreen|darkslateblue|darkslategray|darkslategrey|darkturquoise|darkviolet|deeppink|deepskyblue|dimgray|dimgrey|dodgerblue|firebrick|floralwhite|forestgreen|gainsboro|ghostwhite|gold|goldenrod|greenyellow|grey|honeydew|hotpink|indianred|indigo|ivory|khaki|lavender|lavenderblush|lawngreen|lemonchiffon|lightblue|lightcoral|lightcyan|lightgoldenrodyellow|lightgray|lightgreen|lightgrey|lightpink|lightsalmon|lightseagreen|lightskyblue|lightslategray|lightslategrey|lightsteelblue|lightyellow|limegreen|linen|magenta|mediumaquamarine|mediumblue|mediumorchid|mediumpurple|mediumseagreen|mediumslateblue|mediumspringgreen|mediumturquoise|mediumvioletred|midnightblue|mintcream|mistyrose|moccasin|navajowhite|oldlace|olivedrab|orangered|orchid|palegoldenrod|palegreen|paleturquoise|palevioletred|papayawhip|peachpuff|peru|pink|plum|powderblue|rosybrown|royalblue|saddlebrown|salmon|sandybrown|seagreen|seashell|sienna|skyblue|slateblue|slategray|slategrey|snow|springgreen|steelblue|tan|thistle|tomato|turquoise|violet|wheat|whitesmoke|yellowgreen)\b</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>invalid.deprecated.color.w3c-non-standard-color-name.css</string>
        </dict>
        ...
    </array>
</dict>
...
```

The different appearance is caused by scoping:

*support.constant.color.w3c-standard-color-name.css* (for standard color keywords)
*invalid.deprecated.color.w3c-non-standard-color-name.css* (for extended color keywords)

Comment: Thanks. What is CSS.tmLanguage?

Comment: @CoolGuy It's the default CSS syntax definition for Sublime Text. The file is usually located in Packages.